# How to do make Plot automatically figure out a domain interval?

Tags: plotting

When you tell Wolfram|Alpha to plot something, it automatically figures out a reasonable domain to plot it over. When I [try](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%3D+1000) something like

```
Plot x^2 + y^2 = 1000
```

it automatically translates that to

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 1000, {x, -40, 40}, {y, -40, 40}]
```

and gives me back a nice circle.

Now this isn't even a function, but I'd be pretty happy even if this could be done just for functions, or even only relatively simple ones at that.

I'm pretty new to *Mathematica*, and for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this with *Mathematica*. I just want it to plot the function and figure out the range itself! It drives me nuts to have to say

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -8, 8}]
```

when I have no idea what `f` will look like.

How can I have *Mathematica* figure out a reasonable domain by itself? I don't need it to be perfect, just something that isn't totally unreasonable (e.g. a blank plot). It can't be that hard for a system that can symbolically solve differential equations.

Comment: An interesting question but could you provide additional examples?  How are more complicated functions handled?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I'm not sure if I should be reading between the lines of your comment or if I'm understanding what you're asking me. If you *literally* just want me to run *more* examples, I'd be happy to, just tell me what function you want to see the plot for because I have no idea what you're looking for. But if this is just a subtle way of suggesting that it's unreasonable to expect such a feature to exist because it can't handle arbitrarily complex functions... well yes, I realize nothing in the world can handle arbitrarily complex tasks, but so what?

Comment: No reading between the lines needed.  I merely would like to see how MATLAB is handling some nontrivial examples as a reference for attempting to emulate its behavior.  Also I would like to know what should be done for functions that cannot be symbolically analyzed.  Should we evaluate an arbitrary range of x values and then attempt narrow the plot to an "interesting" part of the result?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Ah. Okay, I just tried more examples and now I see something I never realized before -- the domain seems to always be -8 to +8. :) It always seemed to work just fine so thought it was doing something smarter. Now I kind of want to delete this question...

Comment: Ha, I think we all have done things like that.  Okay, instead of deleting why don't you edit the question to describe what you would like to happen rather than referencing MATLAB?  The idea of an automatic *x* range is interesting, and as user1337's answer shows it's obviously been implemented for Wolfram|Alpha.  I still think some nontrivial examples (with ranges manually selected) would strengthen the question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Done, thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: @Szabolcs: Did you read the comment chain before commenting...

Comment: For the updated question: consider building a function around `RegionPlot` of an `ImplicitRegion` form of your equation. At least for simple cases, `RegionPlot` is capable of reasoning the bounds of a geometric region (v10 functionality). An example: `RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1000, {x, y}]]`

Comment: @kirma: Cool! Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

[se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html):

> `ezplot(fun)` plots the expression `fun(x)` over the default domain `-2π < x < 2π`, where `fun(x)` is an explicit function of only `x`.

(... and pretty much the same for other variations.) That wasn't actually at all as fancy as I expected!

Thus the simplest case:

```
ClearAll[ezplot];

ezplot[expr_, rest___] := Plot[expr, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, rest];
SetAttributes[ezplot, HoldAll]; (* just to act like Plot *)
```

**EDIT**: Now my answer looks strange... why? Because OP extensively edited the question while I was answering it.

Starting point for the edited question:

```
ClearAll[ezregion];

ezregion[expr_, rest___] := RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[expr, {x, y}], rest];
SetAttributes[ezregion, HoldAll];
```

Now you can perform automatic 2D region plot for expressions involving `x` and `y`:

```
ezregion[x^2 + y^2 == 1000]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try typing the equal sign first (=), and then, in words, "plot x^2".

**EDIT:**

You can read more about the Free-Form input [here](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/free-form-linguistic-input/).

Comment: So you're saying I need internet access in order to get this functionality? It takes so long for it to evaluate... at that point I'm just using Wolfram Alpha... or I might as well just give up and use MATLAB.

Comment: I'm afraid so...